# What are the proper permissions for ColdFusion 9 on IIS 7.5 with Windows Authentication

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, windows-authentication

We are running ColdFusion 9 on IIS 7.5.

Our intranet website uses Windows Authentication with the Negotiate provider.

We have set up an Active Directory user group (Web Developers) and assigned the permissions to the web source directory.

Everything works fine for one particular user group.

We created a new group (General Staff) and assigned the permissions to the source directory.

After restarting all of the services involved we end up with 401.3 errors which are Authenticated but Access is denied errors.

The error happens with html as well as cfm files.

To verify access, I browsed the unc path in windows explorer.  All worked well.

Are there permissions other than the actual source directory that need to be set to get past the access is denied errors?

Does ColdFusion run even if the request is an html file?

Comment: What browser are you using?  I ask because we have a similar setup with CF 9 and IIS 7.5 and I have had issues with the Windows challenge/response when using Chrome.  It seems like it does not send the user's credentials automatically and it does not prompt for them either.  Is IE prompting for your credentials when you navigate to a secured page?

Comment: You say that you setup permissions to the source directory.  Did you also setup permissions in IIS?  Or is that what you meant.

Comment: @Miguel-F The problem happens in both browsers.  When I've put myself in the dev group I get through in both browsers. If I take myself out, it fails.  So it's not an issue with the browser.  As far as IIS permissions, the IIS permissions are actually set at the NTFS level so it's really NTFS permisions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning read permissions on the ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig directory to the group in question allows the requests to proceed.