# Cannot authenticate against Windows domain using ColdFusion 10, IIS 7.5, LDAP

Tags: authentication, iis, coldfusion, basic-authentication

We have been struggling on an upgrade from Windows 2003 Server (ColdFusion 8) to Windows 2008 with ColdFusion 10.  We finally have the settings correct to handle and process all of our ColdFusion code, with custom error handlers, and SSL functioning as expected. 
However, when we started to have some users test different applications, we found out that no Domain Users can log in to the website, unless they are part of the Local Machine's Administrators group.  We have another Windows 2008 Server running .NET and authenticating users correctly. I thoroughly compared the settings and they are the same.
This is how it is setup:

- **ColdFusion Services**: all services (5) are running under the Local System, with the exception of the ColdFusion Application Server, which is running under a domain account.
- **IIS**: We have 1 active website  (Main Website) running on it's own Application Pool  Integrated .NET 4.0, running as LocalSystem.
- **Authentication**: Anonymous works, Anonymous account MUST be Application Pool Identity or else it won’t display anything. Basic Authentication is configured, and the default domain is configured.

Any and all help is appreciated as we have been working on this for months and thought the migration was ready to go.  No one on my team is an expert at the installation of ColdFusion or IIS 7.5.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are trying to authenticate your users? Your question references LDAP but it sounds like you are trying to use IIS based authentication.  Do you have a log in form in a ColdFusion template or do you want the browser to prompt for credentials (challenge/response)?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. We are using BASIC authentication via IIS, which goes to a Local A/D server. We are not using Form authentication or anything else of that matter.

Comment: When you say "Basic Authentication" do you mean "Windows Authentication"?  Are you on Windows 2008 or Windows 2008R2?  Also, you shouldn't have to have ".NET 4.0" enabled on ColdFusion sites' application pools, unless maybe you do .Net integration with CF (I don't know about that, I've never worked with .Net).  I usually set application pools to "Not Managed".

Comment: As @cfvonner mentioned, we have our application pools set to "No Managed Code". We are running Windows 2008 R2. We have sites running against our domain with Basic Auth and also Windows Auth. We use Basic Auth for sites that use the `cfhttp` tag (it cannot handle Windows Auth). For user authentication we use Windows Auth. For Basic just enable Basic Auth and then under "Authorization Rules" deny Anonymous Users and add Allow rules for your domain groups/users. Under the specified role or group specify them as "domainname\groupname". Under the specified users as "domainname\username".

Comment: I don't mean Windows Authentication; we are using BASIC (401 Challenge). Turning on BASIC and entering the default Domain still do not allow users on the domain access, even if they are specifically identified as having the appropriate permissions to view folders.

Comment: Changing the App Pool to no managed code should have no effect, but I tried it anyways in desperation. No change.  We are on 2008R2.

Comment: What do you have under "Authorization Rules"? Are you getting prompted for credentials?

Comment: We are getting prompted for credentials. BASIC uses the 401 Handshake, and since we are using custom errors, we have added CF Headers to the custom 401 page: **<cfheader name="WWW-Authenticate" value="Basic realm=#realm#">
<cfheader statuscode="401" statustext="Not Authenticated">**   Our .NET AUTHORIZATION RULES allows all users.   When the browser is prompted, my credentials work (I am in the local Admin group), however, my other standard domain users fail (even with putting in DOMAIN\USERNAME and the password.

Comment: So your custom 401 page is handling the authentication then? Are you using `cflogin`, an LDAP query or some such in that template? I thought you were trying to get this working using IIS settings. (Perhaps this is why you initially tagged this question with LDAP.)

Comment: No, we are adding the CFHEADERS to force the browser for Authentication (see my last post). With BASIC Authentication in IIS, when you view a private page, it does not automatically ask the user for authentication with Custom Errors on. It actually runs the scripts on the Custom 401 page, which does not present the browser for credentials; so we force it (as detailed here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)  The weird part is that my account works because I am an Admin on the server, but no body else's does.

Answer (score 1):

After much ado, I found the answer here: [What are the proper permissions for ColdFusion 9 on IIS 7.5 with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194125/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-coldfusion-9-on-iis-7-5-with-windows-authent)

I needed to give the domain users (which is just a very large A/D group) read-only access to the config folder under the CF10 install location. From then on, it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a fairly robust solution as well, here's an example component (CFC) you could call, which also scrubs out possible injection characters. We've evolved this over the years for authentication so it is fairly battle tested.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

<cffunction access="public" name="init" output="FALSE" returntype="any" hint="This is the pseudo constructor that allows us to play little object games." >

    <cfset variables.ldapserver = application.yoursiteLDAP.server />
    <cfset variables.ldapuser = application.yoursiteLDAP.user />
    <cfset variables.ldappassword = application.yoursiteLDAP.password />
    <cfset variables.ldaptimeout = application.yoursiteLDAP.timeout />
    <cfset variables.ldapsecuremode = application.yoursiteLDAP.securemode />
    <cfset variables.port = application.yoursiteLDAP.port />

    <cfreturn This />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="authenticate" access="public" output="false" returntype="struct" hint="">
    <cfargument name="username" type="string">
    <cfargument name="password" type="string">

    <cfset var returnData = StructNew() />
    <cfset var queryResult = QueryNew('') />
    <cfset var userInfo = "" />

    <cfset arguments.username = scrubStringforLDAPQuery(arguments.username) />

    <cfset userInfo = retrieveUserInfo(arguments.username) />

    <cfset returnData["authenticated"] = false />
    <cfset returnData["detail"] = "" />
    <cfset returnData["user_info"] = QueryNew("") />

    <cftry>
            <cfldap
                    action="query"
                    server="#variables.ldapserver#"
                    username="#userInfo.DN#"
                    password="#arguments.password#"
                    filter="(&(uid=#arguments.username#)(objectClass=account))"
                    name="queryResult"
                    attributes="cn,dn,uid,displayName,objectClass,uidNumber"
                    start="dc=yoursite,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com"
                    maxrows="1"
                    port="#variables.port#"
                    timeout="#variables.ldaptimeout#"
                    secure="#variables.ldapsecuremode#" />

            <cfset returnData["authenticated"] = queryResult.RecordCount EQ 1 />
            <cfset returnData["user_info"] = queryResult />

            <cfcatch>
                    <cfif FindNoCase("Invalid Credentials",cfcatch.Message) LTE 0>
                            <cfrethrow />
                    </cfif>
                    <cfset returnData["detail"] = cfcatch.Message />
            </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfreturn returnData />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="retrieveUserInfo" access="public" output="false" returntype="query" hint="">
    <cfargument name="username" type="string">

    <cfset var queryResult = QueryNew('') />

    <cfset arguments.username = scrubStringforLDAPQuery(arguments.username) />

    <cfldap
            action="query"
            server="#variables.ldapserver#"
            username="#variables.ldapuser#"
            password="#variables.ldappassword#"
            filter="(&(uid=#arguments.username#)(objectClass=account))"
            name="queryResult"
            attributes="cn,dn,uid,displayName,objectClass,uidNumber,shadowExpire,gecos,homeDirectory,loginShell"
            start="dc=yoursite,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com"
            maxrows="10"
            port="#variables.port#"
            timeout="#variables.ldaptimeout#"
            secure="#variables.ldapsecuremode#" />

    <cfif queryResult.RecordCount GT 1>
            <cfthrow message="More than 1 user found in LDAP" detail="More than 1 user matched uid=#arguments.username#" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn queryResult />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="retrieveGroupInfo" access="public" output="false" returntype="query" hint="">
    <cfargument name="groupname" type="string">

    <cfset var queryResult = QueryNew('') />

    <cfset arguments.groupname = scrubStringforLDAPQuery(arguments.groupname) />

    <cfldap
            action="query"
            server="#variables.ldapserver#"
            username="#variables.ldapuser#"
            password="#variables.ldappassword#"
            filter="(&(cn=#arguments.groupname#)(objectClass=posixGroup))"
            name="queryResult"
            attributes="cn,dn,objectClass"
            start="dc=yoursite,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com"
            maxrows="10"
            port="#variables.port#"
            timeout="#variables.ldaptimeout#"
            secure="#variables.ldapsecuremode#" />

    <cfif queryResult.RecordCount GT 1>
            <cfthrow message="More than 1 group found in LDAP" detail="More than 1 group matched uid=#arguments.groupname#" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn queryResult />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="scrubStringforLDAPQuery" access="public" output="false" returntype="string" hint="Removes offensive characters from string for use in an LDAP query">
    <cfargument name="stringToScrub" type="string">
    <cfargument name="blockWildcard" type="boolean" default="false">

    <cfset replaceCharacterList = ";=" />

    <cfif arguments.blockWildcard>
            <cfset replaceCharacterList &= "*" />
    </cfif>

    <cfset arguments.stringToScrub = REReplace(arguments.stringToScrub,"[#replaceCharacterList#]","","all") />

    <cfreturn arguments.stringToScrub />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```